# Can I grep to find matching rows in 2 files using grep+cut but then print back the rest of the row after the cut?

Tags: bash, grep, compare, match, diff

I am looking to find matches anywhere between 2 csv files, email addresses specifically.
If I run this command via bash (I would like to figure out something via bash for now):

```
grep -w --file <(sort -u file1.csv) <(sort -u file2.csv| cut d',' -f2)
```

it works. But there is surrounding character data in the same row that I would like to print out either to stdin or to a new file eventually.  How do I do this diff comparison and still preserve the row data for printing?

```
file1.csv consists of:
email@email.com

file2.csv consists of:
,email@.email.com,123456,"""ABC, Blah Blah."""
```

I would like to do my comparison but join the ABC, Blah Blah data back to the final result.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When having to query data from CSV tables; joining on index like with your email index; SQLite3 is an appropriate tool choice.

It is a nice, common and standard tool to have:

1. Capable of directly importing CSV files.
2. Available for many different platforms.
3. Widely used, light-weight database engine with SQL query language.

Here is an example:

`file1.csv`:

```
email
email@example.com
someone@example.com
```

`file2.csv`:

```
email,phone,description
email@email.com,123456,"""ABC, Blah Blah."""
someone@example.com,7684652,"Foo, bar, baz."
anything@example.net,424255,"Hello kitten"
email@example.com,6578218,"This to be output"
```

When your CSV files have column headers, SQLite3 handles tables creation for you, using columns' name from the CSV:

```bash
#! /bin/sh

sqlite3 :memory: << 'EOF'
.mode csv
.headers on
.import file1.csv emails
.import file2.csv contacts

SELECT c.*
FROM emails AS e
LEFT JOIN contacts AS c
  ON e.email = c.email;
EOF
```

Here is how it all works:

- `sqlite3 :memory:`: Invokes SQLite3 with in-memory database.
- `.mode csv`: Places SQLite3 in CSV mode, so it can work directly with CSV files.
- `.headers on`: Activates output of columns' header.
- `.import file1.csv emails`: Imports `file1.csv` into the `emails` table.
- `.import file2.csv contacts`: Imports `file2.csv` into the `contacts` table.

Here is the actual SQL query, that will `SELECT` `*` all columns from the `contacts AS c` table; when the `c.email = e.email` columns matches with the `LEFT JOIN`ed `emails AS e` table:

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM emails AS e
LEFT JOIN contacts AS c
  ON e.email = c.email;
```

When CSV files don't have columns' headers; tables need be created explicitly with SQL commands before importing the CSV into it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emails (
  email text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE contacts (
  email text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  phone text,
  description text
);
```

Output from this program above:

```
email,phone,description
email@example.com,6578218,"This to be output"
someone@example.com,7684652,"Foo, bar, baz."
```

Comment: I did try this initially with postgres as I have a postgres server with the data in it but I gave up because of the way 1 of my columns is is a json array made it annoying to figure out.  Do you think postgres is another good way to do this?

Comment: @GregGelman I don't know much about Postgress, if it has similar capabilities with CSV, it is already available to your systems and you are used to it; it is, a good option for you.